# iOS Animation Repeat (Completion Block Not Being Called)

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, viewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to get my animation to move back and forth. For example, in a fish tank simulation as such, I am trying to get the fish to move back and forth. I am trying to get this to work infinitely long, however the fish only moves in one direction and the completion block is never being called. Can someone advise me how to call the completion block once the fish reaches the end of the screen or another way to approach this?

Attached is my current code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: fishAnimationDuration, delay: fishAnimationDelay, options: [.allowAnimatedContent, .repeat], animations: {
                fish.frame = CGRect(x: fishXPosEnd, y: fishYPos, width: fishWidth, height: fishHeight)
            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                    fish.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "fishBack")
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: fishAnimationDuration, delay: fishAnimationDelay, options: [.allowAnimatedContent], animations: {
                        fish.frame = CGRect(x: fishXPos, y: fishYPos, width: fishWidth, height: fishHeight)
                   })
 })
```

Comment: A repeated animation never completes.

Comment: So what is the best way to repeat this animation so it would call the completion block every time it reaches the end? I want it to run infinitely long.

Comment: @Yeeee to stop animation just call `fish.layer.removeAllAnimations()`, then completion block will get called i suppose, better way is call another animate block to reset the view, then put your completion block there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion block isn't called when `repeat` is in the options because the repeating animation never completes.

In your case I would remove the `repeat` option. Then in the completion handler of the 2nd animation, call the method containing these animation blocks so the pair of animations are called again.